# Rotate globe in cesium map

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I'm rotating my Cesium globe through this code:

```
spinGlobe( dynamicRate ){
    var previousTime = Date.now();

    this.viewer.scene.postRender.addEventListener(function (scene, time){
        var spinRate = dynamicRate;
        var currentTime = Date.now();
        var delta = ( currentTime - previousTime ) / 1000;
        previousTime = currentTime;
        this.viewer.scene.camera.rotate(Cesium.Cartesian3.UNIT_Z, -spinRate * delta);
    });
}
```

Now I want to stop it, so how I can I stop this globe rotation on a particular event?

Answer (score 1):

There's a `removeEventListener` that needs to be passed a reference to the same function that you provided to `addEventListener`.

Here's a [Sandcastle Demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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). Note that this demo does not protect against the user clicking "Spin" multiple times, so the user will need to hit "Stop" an equal number of times.  Real (non-demo) code should take care not to add multiple event listeners for the same event.

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");

var previousTime = Date.now();
var spinRate = 1.0;

function applyGlobeSpin() {
    var currentTime = Date.now();
    var delta = ( currentTime - previousTime ) / 1000;
    previousTime = currentTime;
    viewer.scene.camera.rotate(Cesium.Cartesian3.UNIT_Z, -spinRate * delta);
}

function startSpinGlobe() {
    previousTime = Date.now();
    viewer.clock.onTick.addEventListener(applyGlobeSpin);
}

function stopSpinGlobe() {
    viewer.clock.onTick.removeEventListener(applyGlobeSpin);
}

Sandcastle.addToolbarButton("Spin", startSpinGlobe);
Sandcastle.addToolbarButton("Stop", stopSpinGlobe);
```